# Pandas promotes int to float when filtering

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Pandas seems to be promoting an `int` to a `float` when filtering. I've provided a simple snippet below but I've got a much more complex example which I believe this promotion leads to incorrect filtering because it compares `floats`. Is there a way around this? I read that this is a change of behaviour between different versions of pandas - it certainly didn't use to be the case.

Below you can see, it changes `[4 13]` and `[5 14]` to `[4.0 13.0]` and `[5.0 14.0]`.

```
In [53]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2' : [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]})  
    ...: df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2, 3], 'col2' : [10, 11, 12]})                                                                                             

In [54]: df1                                                                                                                                                                
Out[54]: 
   col1  col2
0     1    10
1     2    11
2     3    12
3     4    13
4     5    14

In [55]: df2                                                                                                                                                                
Out[55]: 
   col1  col2
0     1    10
1     2    11
2     3    12

In [56]: df1[~df1.isin(df2)]                                                                                                                                                
Out[56]: 
   col1  col2
0   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN
3   4.0  13.0
4   5.0  14.0

In [57]: df1[~df1.isin(df2)].dropna()                                                                                                                                       
Out[57]: 
   col1  col2
3   4.0  13.0
4   5.0  14.0

In [58]: df1[~df1.isin(df2)].dtypes                                                                                                                                         
Out[58]: 
col1    float64
col2    float64
dtype: object

In [59]: df1.dtypes                                                                                                                                                         
Out[59]: 
col1    int64
col2    int64
dtype: object

In [60]: df2.dtypes                                                                                                                                                         
Out[60]: 
col1    int64
col2    int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: It's not because of float comparison, it's because of the `NaN`'s.  You could use the `Int64` dtype which has integer `NaN`'s if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no float comparison happening here.  `isin` is returning `NaN`'s for missing data, and since you are using `numpy`'s `int64`, the result is getting cast to `float64`.

In 0.24, pandas added a [nullable integer dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html), which you can use here.

---

```
df1 = df1.astype('Int64')
df2 = df2.astype('Int64')

df1[~df1.isin(df2)]
```

```
   col1  col2
0   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN
3     4    13
4     5    14
```

---

Just be aware that if you wanted to use numpy operations on the result, numpy would treat the above as an array with dtype `object`.