# Reliable way of dropping rows in df1 which are also in df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a scenario where I have an `existing` dataframe and I have a `new` dataframe which contains rows which might be in the `existing` frame but might also have new rows. I have struggled to find a reliable way to drop these existing rows from the `new` dataframe by comparing it with the `existing` dataframe.

I've done my homework. The solution seems to be to use `isin()`. However, I find that this has hidden dangers. In particular:

[pandas get rows which are NOT in other dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe/47107164#47107164)

[Pandas cannot compute isin with a duplicate axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54528757/pandas-cannot-compute-isin-with-a-duplicate-axis)

[Pandas promotes int to float when filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58662187/pandas-promotes-int-to-float-when-filtering)

Is there a way to reliably filter out rows from one dataframe based on membership/containment in another dataframe? A simple usecase which doesn't capture corner cases is shown below. Note that I want to remove rows in `new` that are in `existing` so that `new` only contains rows not in `existing`. A simpler problem of updating `existing` with new rows from `new` can be achieved with `pd.merge()` + `DataFrame.drop_duplicates()`

```
In [53]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2' : [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]})  
    ...: df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2, 3], 'col2' : [10, 11, 12]})                                                                                             

In [54]: df1                                                                                                                                                                
Out[54]: 
   col1  col2
0     1    10
1     2    11
2     3    12
3     4    13
4     5    14

In [55]: df2                                                                                                                                                                
Out[55]: 
   col1  col2
0     1    10
1     2    11
2     3    12

In [56]: df1[~df1.isin(df2)]                                                                                                                                                
Out[56]: 
   col1  col2
0   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN
3   4.0  13.0
4   5.0  14.0

In [57]: df1[~df1.isin(df2)].dropna()                                                                                                                                       
Out[57]: 
   col1  col2
3   4.0  13.0
4   5.0  14.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anti-Join Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516664/anti-join-pandas)

Comment: `df1[~df1.isin(df2).all(1)]` ?

Comment: @konvas I'm not sure - I can use merge + drop_duplicates(). However, I need a way to also leave just the new rows in the `new` - for example, I might want to persist those. So it's not just updating `existing` - its also about leaving `new` with just new rows that are not in `existing`

Comment: @anky_91 how is this different from `df1[~df1.isin(df2)].dropna()`

Comment: Sorry if i didn't get the question, if you don't want sequence of rows to be considered, below answer is what you want

Comment: related : [Pandas analogue to SQL MINUS / EXCEPT operator, using multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235226/pandas-analogue-to-sql-minus-except-operator-using-multiple-columns/56235551#56235551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## We can use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator = True` + [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and [`DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

```
df_filtered=( df1.merge(df2,how='outer',indicator=True)
                 .query("_merge == 'left_only'")
                 .drop('_merge',axis=1) )
print(df_filtered)

   col1  col2
3     4    13
4     5    14
```

---

if now for example we change a value of row 0:

```
df1.iat[0,0]=3
```

---

row 0 is no longer filtered

```
df_filtered=( df1.merge(df2,how='outer',indicator=True)
                 .query("_merge == 'left_only'")
                 .drop('_merge',axis=1) )
print(df_filtered)

   col1  col2
0     3    10
3     4    13
4     5    14
```

---

## **Step by step**

```
df_filtered=( df1.merge(df2,how='outer',indicator=True)
 )
print(df_filtered)
   col1  col2      _merge
0     3    10   left_only
1     2    11        both
2     3    12        both
3     4    13   left_only
4     5    14   left_only
5     1    10  right_only
```

---

```
df_filtered=( df1.merge(df2,how='outer',indicator=True).query("_merge == 'left_only'")
 )
print(df_filtered)
   col1  col2     _merge
0     3    10  left_only
3     4    13  left_only
4     5    14  left_only
```

---

```
df_filtered=( df1.merge(df2,how='outer',indicator=True)
                 .query("_merge == 'left_only'")
                 .drop('_merge',axis=1)
 )
print(df_filtered)
   col1  col2
0     3    10
3     4    13
4     5    14
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try Series `isin`. It is independent from `index`. I.e, It only checks on values. You just need to convert columns of each dataframe to series of tuples to create mask

```
s1 = df1.agg(tuple, axis=1)
s2 = df2.agg(tuple, axis=1)

df1[~s1.isin(s2)]

Out[538]:
   col1  col2
3     4    13
4     5    14
```